# Why fiddlesticks?

Tags: catch-phrases

"Fiddlesticks" is used as a mild expletive or to express disbelief. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google search offers little comfort.  [Michael Quinion](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-fid1.htm) provides one of the best summaries; it seems to have developed through meaning something inconsequential.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that *fiddlesticks* sounds funny and starts with an *f*, like another expletive.

Comment: D'oh! Fancy not looking at World Wide Words!